# Using System.DateTime in a C# Lambda expression gives an exception

Tags: c#, datetime, lambda, expression-trees

I tried to implement a suggestion that came up in another question: [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187322/how-can-i-use-a-html-helper-method-in-an-extension-method)

Snippet here:

```
 public static class StatusExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlString StatusBox<TModel>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, RowInfo>> ex
        )
        {
            var createdEx =
                Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, DateTime>>(
                    Expression.Property(ex.Body, "Created"),
                    ex.Parameters
                );
            var modifiedEx =
                Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, DateTime>>(
                    Expression.Property(ex.Body, "Modified"),
                    ex.Parameters
                );
            var a = "a" + helper.HiddenFor(createdEx) +
                helper.HiddenFor(modifiedEx);
            return new HtmlString(
                "Some things here ..." +
                helper.HiddenFor(createdEx) +
                helper.HiddenFor(modifiedEx)
            );
        }
    }
```

When implemented I am getting the following exception which I don't really understand. The exception points to the line starting with "var createdEx ="

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]' cannot be used for return type 'System.DateTime'
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
```

Can anyone help me out and suggest what I could do to resolve the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allow the lambda return a nullable datetime by adding a question mark:
`var createdEx = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, DateTime?>>...`

Answer (score 2):

The shorthand of adding a question mark after the type allows for a Nullable.  You will probably want to change that in both signatures here.  Keep in mind that this gives you the possibility of passing null DateTimes as hidden parameters though, which may not be what you want.  You might instead wish to keep this code and ensure that you only pass it non null DateTime's instead.

```
 public static class StatusExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlString StatusBox<TModel>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, RowInfo>> ex
        )
        {
            var createdEx =
                Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, DateTime?>>(
                    Expression.Property(ex.Body, "Created"),
                    ex.Parameters
                );
            var modifiedEx =
                Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, DateTime?>>(
                    Expression.Property(ex.Body, "Modified"),
                    ex.Parameters
                );
            var a = "a" + helper.HiddenFor(createdEx) +
                helper.HiddenFor(modifiedEx);
            return new HtmlString(
                "Some things here ..." +
                helper.HiddenFor(createdEx) +
                helper.HiddenFor(modifiedEx)
            );
        }
    }
```