# How can I use Html.BeginForm in a custom helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

So I am trying to convert this razor syntax in a .cshtml view into a helper extension in .cs. There is an awesome post on this by Darin here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8187441/1026459. However, I am having some issues getting it to work.

This is the plain markup

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Restore", "GlobalCrud"))
{
 @Html.Hidden("entityId", "Id")
 <input class="ui-icon ui-icon-power" type="submit" 
  onclick="return confirm('Clicking OK will restore this record');" 
 />
}
```

This is the extention

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditOrDelete(this HtmlHelper html)
{
  var s = html.BeginForm();
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(s + " additional fields " + "</form>");
}
```

This is the use:

```
@using namespace.CustomHelper
@Html.EditOrDelete()
```

This is the output:

```
<form method="post" action="/Completed/Manage">
System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm additional fields 
</form>
```

The helper extention for the most part produces what I need. However, I am uncertain how I should be converting this back to a proper html string. The return includes `System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm` in the text. I am adding `" additional fields "` for brevity here because there is no issue there. The addition of `</form>` is there because I know that the normal `using` statement that goes with `@Html.BeginForm()` adds the `</form>` tag when it disposes.

How can I properly return the form generated by `.BeginForm`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static void EditOrDelete(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        using (html.BeginForm())
        {
            html.ViewContext.Writer.Write("additional fields");
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@using namespace.CustomHelper
@{Html.EditOrDelete();}
```

emits:

```
<form action="/" method="post">additional fields</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Darin! Epic :) I was having issues with actually managing to get anything to appear inside the form with the using statement so changing it void seemed only natural. What I was missing was the ViewContext writer.

Comment: +1 love it, simple and works!  I can now auto insert the AntiForgeryToken with my own form helper

Answer (score 0):

Calling `BeginForm` renders the form tag, so you don't need to do anything except call that method.

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditOrDelete(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    using(html.BeginForm())
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(" additional fields ");
    }
}
```

The using statement will cause `.Dispose()` to be called prior to the method returing, causing the string to written after the closing form tag.  Write the string to the response using `html.ViewContext.Writer.Write` instead.  (see [Darin Dimitrov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10148848/21461))

wrapping the call in a using will automatically cause the ending form tag to be rendered as well, when `Dispose` is called.

Comment: This won't work. The additional fields will be emitted outside the form in the final markup.

Comment: You're right. The using statement is executing `.Dispose()` before returning from the method.